# Can a football team buy and sell a player in the same transfer window?

Tags: rules, football, transfer

For example, the current transfer window for most leagues in Europe ends tomorrow.

Manchester United bought Depay from PSV this window. Could they sell him tomorrow if they wanted? Or do they need to wait until the mid-season transfer window at least?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**YES**

It has happened last sunday (30/08/2015).
Jelle Vossen was [transferred from Burnley to Club Bruges](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFcQFjALahUKEwjng--SntXHAhWD0RQKHXvAAQE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dailymail.co.uk%2Fsport%2Ffootball%2Farticle-3216874%2FBurnley-sell-striker-Jelle-Vossen-Club-Bruges-just-eight-weeks-signing-him.html&ei=V0nlVaf8H4OjU_uAhwg&usg=AFQjCNFuSp_Mcp_-KtCTWW6vVW9YJ1RiVw&sig2=xptnJl7dDWZU703Dq9BOEw) after only buying him this transfer window from KRC Genk.

**Play for maximum two teams in one season**

However, there is a rule saying a player can only play for maximum two clubs in one season. If for instance Depay would have played an **official** match for PSV, then an official match for Man Utd, he would no longer be able to play for a third club, even on loan.

> [Regulations on the Status and Transfer of Players](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/affederation/administration/regulations_on_the_status_and_transfer_of_players_en_33410.pdf) Chapter III, Article 5.3
>
> Players may be registered with a maximum of three clubs during one
>   season. During this period, the player is only eligible to play offi
>   cial matches for two clubs. As an exception to this rule, a player
>   moving between two clubs belonging to associations with overlapping
>   seasons (i.e. start of the season in summer/autumn as opposed to
>   winter/spring) may be eligible to play in offi cial matches for a
>   third club during the relevant season, provided he has fully complied
>   with his contractual obligations towards his previous clubs. Equally,
>   the provisions relating to the registration periods (article 6) as
>   well as to the minimum length of a contract (article 18 paragraph 2)
>   must be respected.